# Using db2 on iSeries, issue with SQL insert into from () where () not in ()

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I need to build an index of keys across several library/tables.  Have already done this many times for single field indexes, but getting stuck trying to create basically the same thing with multiple fields.

In all the examples below I have abbreviated to show all the aspects but with a far smaller list of elements to make this easier to digest. Apologies if I made any renaming errors.

Here is an example of a working query that runs every night in a scheduled job:

```
    INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABL_X1
    (SELECT DISTINCT T1.FIELD1 FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT T1.FIELD1 FROM LIB1NAME.TABL T1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT T1.FIELD1 FROM LIB2NAME.TABL T1 ) T1 
     WHERE T1.FIELD1 NOT IN (SELECT T1.FIELD1 FROM LIBMAST.TABL_X1) ) ;
```

Here is the test version of my insert query, as a select statement to show what records should be getting imported.  This works fine, shows what it should.

```
    SELECT T2.* FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT  'PA' AS FIELD1, T1.NAME2 AS FIELD2, T1.NAME3 AS FIELD3, T1.NAME4 AS FIELD4, T1.NAME5L AS FIELD5 FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB1NAME.TABL T1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB2NAME.TABL T1  ) T1
    ) T2
       WHERE (T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3, T2.FIELD4, T2.FIELD5) NOT IN 
      (SELECT T3.FIELD1, T3.FIELD2, T3.FIELD3, T3.FIELD4, T3.FIELD5 FROM LIBMAST.TABLKEYS T3) ;
```

This is the insert statement that isn't working.  Only the first line of code has changed.

```
    INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABLKEYS  
    (SELECT DISTINCT  'PA' AS FIELD1, T1.NAME2 AS FIELD2, T1.NAME3 AS FIELD3, T1.NAME4 AS FIELD4, T1.NAME5L AS FIELD5 FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB1NAME.TABL T1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB2NAME.TABL T1  ) T1
    ) T2
       WHERE (T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3, T2.FIELD4, T2.FIELD5) NOT IN 
      (SELECT T3.FIELD1, T3.FIELD2, T3.FIELD3, T3.FIELD4, T3.FIELD5 FROM LIBMAST.TABLKEYS T3) ;
```

Here is the first part of the error message I get:

SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -104
Message: [SQL0104] Token T2 was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token T2.  Token T2 is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token

I don't see what is different with syntax but obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You removed the `SELECT` and replaced it with `INSERT`....you need to leave the `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABLKEYS
SELECT T2.* FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT  'PA' AS FIELD1, T1.NAME2 AS FIELD2, T1.NAME3 AS FIELD3, T1.NAME4 AS FIELD4, T1.NAME5L AS FIELD5 FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB1NAME.TABL T1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT T1.NAME2, T1.NAME3, T1.NAME4, T1.NAME5 FROM LIB2NAME.TABL T1  ) T1
    ) T2
       WHERE (T2.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2, T2.FIELD3, T2.FIELD4, T2.FIELD5) NOT IN 
      (SELECT T3.FIELD1, T3.FIELD2, T3.FIELD3, T3.FIELD4, T3.FIELD5 FROM LIBMAST.TABLKEYS T3) ;
```

**EDIT**
In reference to your "I didn't need the extra select wrapper" for the first query.

The syntax of the statement is always `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT FROM <...>`

Your first statement simplified is:

```
INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABL_X1
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.FIELD1 FROM <...> T1
```

Your second select simplified is:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM <...> T2
```

That's the results set you intend to insert into another table.  Thus:

```
INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABLKEYS
  SELECT T2.* FROM <...> T2
```

If the select is only returning 5 columns and TABLKEYS has 10 columns, you need to specify the 5 columns you have values for like so:

```
INSERT INTO LIBMAST.TABLKEYS (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
  SELECT T2.* FROM <...> T2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I can try that, but please also look at the first example that is currently working.  I didn't need the extra select wrapper in that query.

Comment: adding the additional [select t2.* from ] gave me a different error.  "Statement contains wrong number of values."

Comment: Unless you include an explicit list if columns into the insert table, you select statement must return a value for every column in the table to be inserted into.

Comment: Because this is a list of keys in existing records, that do not exist in the key table, there will always be values in each of the fields to be inserted.

Comment: Looks like your select returns 5 fields...how many fields are in LIBMAST.TABLKEYS?

Comment: There are actually 10 fields in TablKeys.  I tried to shorten this down for the example.  Notice the inner select only gets 4 of the 5 fields.  The outer select creates the 5th key with 'PA' as the value.  Then the insert should add records that don't match 'PA' with whatever other values were found across all locations.

Comment: There is no "outer select", that would imply a join.  The only columns in T2 are from this part of the statement, `SELECT DISTINCT  'PA' AS FIELD1, T1.NAME2 AS FIELD2, T1.NAME3 AS FIELD3, T1.NAME4 AS FIELD4, T1.NAME5L AS FIELD5`   you need to have 10 columns, or you need to specify the 5 columns in Tablkeys that you have values for.

Comment: Sorry for choice of word.  Not defining a join, outer or otherwise.  Only attempting to draw attention to the first select statement in my example rather than the subquery select (outer of the two selects).  I am trying to understand your point.  Maybe it would be better to ignore the 2nd example and look at the difference in syntax between the 1st and 3rd examples.  They appear to have the same syntax other than having more fields in the 3rd example.  And, adding the code you suggested to the 2nd example also didn't work.

Comment: @Dennis, I don't know how to explain it any clearer.  If you have a working `SELECT` statement, all you need to do if add `INSERT INTO mytable` in front of the **unchanged** select.  But your select has to return the same number of columns as is in the table you want the results inserted into.  Otherwise, your insert has to specify which columns the selects values are for.  The rest will be defaulted.

Comment: Answer was that the keytable included a field it should not have.  I was trying to insert 10 fields into a table defined with 11 fields.  Your persistence and clear answer helped a great deal.  Thank you!